# Unity 5.3 dropdown menu

Tags: drop-down-menu, unity-game-engine

I am trying to set the text of my dropdown menu options by scripting but I'm geting this error

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

My code:

```c#
function Start () {
    var dropdown = GameObject.Find("Dropdown");
    dropdown.options.Clear();
    dropdown.options.Add(new dropdown.OptionData("tile1"));
}
```

This is my first project in Unity.

Comment: Are you sure the Dropdown is named "Dropdown"? It seems like find returns null

Comment: yes, i have already checked that

Comment: and are you sure that the dropdown does not have a parent in the hierachy? (or has this question already been solved?)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that Dropdown does not exist yet in the scene when Start() is called. Perhaps consider adding a public field instead of using GameObject.Find():

```
public GameObject dropdown;
void Start()
{
//... your code here
}
```

Then in the scene, drag your "Dropdown" object onto the object this script is on.